# jQuery.mouseover is returning event from nested element instead of the element where the listener is attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(this) OR event.target OR var input = $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388019/this-or-event-target-or-var-input-this)

I've got the following HTML

```
<span>Foo <b>Bar</b></span>
```

and the following JS

```
$("span").mouseover(function(event) {
    ...
});
```

When I hover over `Foo` `$(event.target)` is the `<span>` element, but when I hover over `Bar` `$(event.target)` is the `<b>` element

How do I get the element I want without checking if I get the `<b>`and then selecting the parent!?

Comment: `event.target` always refers to the element the event originated. `this` always refers to the element the event handler was bound to (well, not with event delegation). Just like without jQuery.

Comment: Use the current syntax: `$("span").on('mouseover', function(event) { ... });` (Had accidentally posted as answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget`. It's a reference to the element which has the event listener. To get an in-depth explanation read up on event order, bubbling and capturing. Well worth the time: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html